# find: invalid predicate when using -newermt

Tags: linux, command

I am  using a find command to get files between a certain time and tar it with the following command,

```
  find /lag/cnn -max-depth 3 -newermt "2013-12-19 00:00" -o -type f -newermt "2013-12-16 00:00" -print0 | 
   xargs -0 tar acf out.tar.gz
```

but when i run this command am getting: find: invalid predicate `-newermt' . what is the problem? and how i can work around this.

UPDATES:
What i am actually trying to do is,
path is (used ls -lrt /lag/cnn/*/*):

```
        /lag/cnn/Example1/one/a.tar.gz
        /lag/cnn/Example1/two/a.tar.gz
        /lag/cnn/Example1/three/a.tar.gz
         /lag/cnn/Example2/one/a.tar.gz
```

I am using grep for Example1 and got a list in sample.txt as follows,

```
        /lag/cnn/Example1/one/a.tar.gz
       /lag/cnn/Example1/two/a.tar.gz
       /lag/cnn/Example1/three/a.tar.gz
```

from this sample.txt i want to tar files based on time.since touch doesn't work on a file. i opted find command.thing is i need to do this from root directory.

```
          touch /lag/cnn/*/* start -d "2013-12-19 00:00"
```

will not work for sure. So is there any way to read files between a certain time and tar it or how to use this touch to use -newer and find files between certain time.

Answer (score 8):

Your version of `find` doesn't support the `-newermt` predicate, so you cannot use it. As a workaround, you could use the `-newer` predicate. That predicate needs a file as a reference: instead of an absolute modification date, it will use the modification date of the file. You can create appropriate "marker files" for this purpose, for example:

```
touch /tmp/mark.start -d "2013-12-19 00:00"
touch /tmp/mark.end -d "2013-12-16 00:00"
```

And then rewrite using `-newer` predicate:

```
find /some/path -newer /tmp/mark.start
```

Btw it looks like your conditions were wrong: you have `-newermt` twice with different dates, which in your example would get all files newer then the older date, ignoring the newer date. Maybe you wanted to do something like this instead:

```
find /some/path -newer /tmp/mark.start ! -newer /tmp/mark.end
```

Finally, your `tar` won't work if the argument list is too long and `xargs` splits to multiple executions, because all executions will recreate the `tar` file. You need to use the `-T` flag of `tar` instead of `xargs`:

```
find /some/path -print0 | tar acf out.tar.gz --null -T-
```

Comment: The path am trying to extract files between certain date is /lag/cnn/*/*/* that's why i used -maxdepth 3 if i ls this path i will get list of all the files in that path, from that i will grep the list i want from which i need to tar files between certain time.I need to do these from root directory .touch didn't work for /lag/cnn/*/*/*  or is there any way to use touch  with out actually cd to particular path.

Comment: See my updated answer: I put the markers in `/tmp/`, but they could be anywhere. In the examples I focused on the key points, that's why omitted your other parameters such as `-maxdepth 3`. You can add whatever you need on top of those examples.

Comment: @user2572985 I don't understand your update. Not a single word in it. And you're using the `touch` example I gave you incorrectly. You should use it exactly as I gave you. It seems you didn't understand at all what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

### **Find files newer than "start" and older than "end"**

```
touch /tmp/mark.start -d "2016-02-16 00:00"

touch a -d "2016-02-15 00:01"

touch b -d "2016-02-16 00:01"

touch c -d "2016-02-17 00:00"

touch d -d "2016-02-18 00:00"

touch e -d "2016-02-19 00:01"

touch /tmp/mark.end -d "2016-02-19 00:00"
```

Command: `find . -type f -newer /tmp/mark.start ! -newer /tmp/mark.end`

========================================================================

## Output:

```
-bash-3.2$ find . -type f -newer /tmp/mark.start ! -newer /tmp/mark.end

./d

./b

./c

-bash-3.2$
```